# What language is Cadence's Emanger *.ecom files written in?

Tags: verilog, hdl

I know this is a long shot but I thought I would ask while I am waiting for the FAE to get back to me. This is related to Cadence Verilog simulations and regressions.

I am trying to debug an *.ecom file and I am not sure what language it is written in. Here is a sample of the code:

```
var vsofs : vm_vsof = vm_manager.read_session("<1>");

// create context
var sessions : list of vm_attribute_container;
sessions = vm_manager.get_all_sessions().as_a(list of vm_attribute_container);
var curr_context : vm_context = vm_manager.create_context({sessions}, "session_stats");
curr_context.export_to_csv(RUNS, "<2>");
```

And this script is invoked like this:

```
 > emanager -b -c "setup; @create_csv.ecom \
   ../vsof/smoke_regr.user.11_03_11_16_15_52_7509/chip_passing.vsof \
   ../vsof/smoke_regr.user.11_03_11_16_15_52_7509/"
```

PS - If there is a better stackexchange place to put this question let me know.

Answer (score 1):

It is the "e" language. and to print:

```
out("Variable foo=",foo);
```